# Freeze different elements using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 3 different elements at the top of the page. I would like to freeze them with responsiveness. My code is like below.

```css
#prayer_time .page-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 290px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99; 
}

#prayer_time .col-md-12 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 75px;
    z-index: 99;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 78.5%; 
}
```

```html
<main id="content" role="main" class="main pointer-event">    
    <div class="content container-fluid" id="prayer_time">
        <div class="page-header">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <!-- more code here -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header p-2">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link">
                                January
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- more <li> here -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row gx-2 gx-lg-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 mb-3 my-lg-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="table-responsive datatable-custom">
                        <table id="columnSearchDatatable" class="table table-borderless">
                            <thead class="thead-light">
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- more code here -->
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="set-rows">
                                <!-- more code here -->
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

I would like to freeze `<div class="page-header">`,`<div class="col-md-12">` and `<thead>` of `<table id="columnSearchDatatable" class="table table-borderless">`.

These code freeze a row but I am not getting responsiveness.

Comment: please provide snippet code with complete code (html, css...)

Comment: Thanks @aflyzer. I edited my post. Please check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position : sticky` instead. If you want to children element sticky hide previous add `background color: white` (for example) and `top: 0;` to your element.
If you want to show all sticky element one under others, add `top: "calculate height of previous sticky element";`

```css
.content{
background-color:gray;
height:40px;
overflow:auto;
}

#prayer_time .page-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    left: 290px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99; 
}

#prayer_time .col-md-12 {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: gray;
    z-index: 99;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 78.5%; 
}
```

```html
<main id="content" role="main" class="main pointer-event">    
    <div class="content container-fluid" id="prayer_time">
        <div class="page-header">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                header
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header p-2">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link">
                                January
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- more <li> here -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row gx-2 gx-lg-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 mb-3 my-lg-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="table-responsive datatable-custom">
                        <table id="columnSearchDatatable" class="table table-borderless">
                            <thead class="thead-light">
                                <tr>
                                    thead
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="set-rows">
                                body
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks @aflyzer. Yes, I would like show all sticky element one under others. Could you please show me any other sample of this issue ?